# What happens to a Win7 striped Volume if I have to reinstall the OS

Tags: windows-7, raid

So today I decided to stripe two identical 1.5GB drives (via the Win7 Management Console) to make a single 3GB drive that should perform faster. I'm slightly worried though. I know that it is more likely to fail since a failure to either one of the drives will mean a loss of the entire volume.  My question though, is what will happen if I have to reinstall the the OS (Win7). My boot drive is a completely separate drive.

I am concerned that since this is not a hardware/firmware solution that I will lose important information about the striping if I have to wipe out Win7 from the boot drive for some reason.  I'm thinking that if I reinstall Win7 that I will also necessarily lose all of the info on the Striped Volume. Is this assumption valid? Does anybody have any experience doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before installing Windows, disconnect the RAID drives. Reconnect them after you have installed and configured Windows, and restart before doing any disk configuration explained below.

After you reinstall Windows, connect the drives and restart, the drives will be labeled in **Disk Management** as "**Foreign**". You must import those foreign volumes in order for them to be recognized and function normally again. You shouldn't lose any data in this process.

In **Disk Management**, right click the volume that is labelled "**Foreign**" then click "**Import foreign disks**". Windows will then import the RAID configuration, mount the volume and you can then access it.

Another status the disk may show in Disk Management is "**Not Initialized**". This can occur when Windows recognized the RAID configuration but Disk Management encountered a problem creating the end of sector marker and GUID partition table.

The process for this is just as simple. Right click the disk marked "**Not Initialized**" and click **Initialize**.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771775.aspx#BKMK_4